# Formatar a Data pondo o mês com a primeira letra em Maiúscula

Tags: delphi, delphi-10

Sei que tem vários outros tópicos de formatação de data mais não achei uma com a minha duvida...
Segundo a documentação do [Delphi](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.FormatDateTime) formata-se a data segundo a tabela abaixo.

```
d ------------|Exibe o dia como um número sem um zero inicial (1-31).
dd -----------|Exibe o dia como um número com um zero à esquerda (01-31).
ddd ----------|Exibe o dia como uma abreviação (Sun-Sat) usando as strings dadas pela variável global ShortDayNames .
dddd ---------|Exibe o dia como um nome completo (domingo a sábado) usando as strings dadas pela variável global LongDayNames .
ddddd --------|Exibe a data usando o formato fornecido pela variável global ShortDateFormat .
ddddd --------|Exibe a data usando o formato fornecido pela variável global LongDateFormat.
m ------------|Exibe o mês como um número sem um zero inicial (1-12). Se o especificador m segue imediatamente um especificador h ou hh, o minuto em vez do mês é exibido.
mm -----------|Exibe o mês como um número com um zero inicial (01-12). Se o especificador mm seguir imediatamente um especificador h ou hh, será exibido o minuto em vez do mês.
mmm ----------|Exibe o mês como uma abreviação (Jan-Dec) usando as strings dadas pela variável global ShortMonthNames .
mmmm ---------|Exibe o mês como um nome completo (janeiro-dezembro) usando as strings dadas pela variável global LongMonthNames .
yy -----------|Exibe o ano como um número de dois dígitos (00 a 99).
yyyy ---------|Exibe o ano como um número de quatro dígitos (0000-9999).
'xx' / "xx" --|Os caracteres entre aspas simples ou duplas são exibidos dessa forma e não afetam a formatação.
```

Exemplo de uso para formatar a Data:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var S : string;
begin
  S := SysUtils.FormatDateTime('dd "de " mmmm "de " yyyy, Now());
  Label1.Caption := S;
end;
```

Como ver não tem uma opção para sair o mês com a primeira letra em Maiúsculo
teria uma outra alternativa para fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu fiz assim e deu certo.

segue o código.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
S : string;
Format: TFormatSettings;
begin
  if MonthOf(Now) = 1  then Format.LongMonthNames[1]  := 'Janeiro'   else
  if MonthOf(Now) = 2  then Format.LongMonthNames[2]  := 'Fevereiro' else
  if MonthOf(Now) = 3  then Format.LongMonthNames[3]  := 'Março'     else
  if MonthOf(Now) = 4  then Format.LongMonthNames[4]  := 'Abril'     else
  if MonthOf(Now) = 5  then Format.LongMonthNames[5]  := 'Maio'      else
  if MonthOf(Now) = 6  then Format.LongMonthNames[6]  := 'Junho'     else
  if MonthOf(Now) = 7  then Format.LongMonthNames[7]  := 'Julho'     else
  if MonthOf(Now) = 8  then Format.LongMonthNames[8]  := 'Agosto'    else
  if MonthOf(Now) = 9  then Format.LongMonthNames[9]  := 'Setembro'  else
  if MonthOf(Now) = 10 then Format.LongMonthNames[10] := 'Otubro'    else
  if MonthOf(Now) = 11 then Format.LongMonthNames[11] := 'Novenbro'  else
  if MonthOf(Now) = 12 then Format.LongMonthNames[12] := 'Dezembro';
  S := SysUtils.FormatDateTime('dd "de " mmmm "de " yyyy, Now());
end;
```

Assim funciona bem e só o mês fica em Maiúsculo.
Testa ai se der certo da uma +1.

Answer (score 0):

O mais simples é converter a letra após a atribuição à variável:

`procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var
    s : string;
  begin
    s := FormatDateTime('dd" de "mmmm" de "yyyy', date());
    s[7] := UpCase(s[7]);
    ShowMessage(s);
  end;`